# Shuffling along a given axis in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, dataloader

I have the a dataset that gets loaded in  with the following dimension `[batch_size, seq_len, n_features]` (e.g. torch.Size([16, 600, 130])).

I want to be able to shuffle this data along the sequence length `axis=1` without altering the batch ordering or the feature vector ordering in PyTorch.

Further explanation: For exemplification let's say my batch size is 3, sequence length is 3 and number of features is 2.

example:
`tensor([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]],[[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]],[[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]]])`  I want to be able to randomly shuffle the following way:

`tensor([[[3,3],[1,1],[2,2]],[[6,6],[5,5],[4,4]],[[8,8],[7,7],[9,9]]])`

Are there any PyTorch functions that will do that automatically for me, or does anyone know what would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: I just noticed that the permutation for each row is different in your example. Is this what you intend? In my answer, the permutation will always be the same across rows.

Comment: The permutation for each row I am looking for is supposed to be at random. So your method is not doing what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.randperm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randperm.html).

For tensor `t`, you can use:

```
t[:,torch.randperm(t.shape[1]),:]
```

For your example:

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]],[[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]],[[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]]])
>>> t
tensor([[[1, 1],
         [2, 2],
         [3, 3]],

        [[4, 4],
         [5, 5],
         [6, 6]],

        [[7, 7],
         [8, 8],
         [9, 9]]])
>>> t[:,torch.randperm(t.shape[1]),:]
tensor([[[2, 2],
         [3, 3],
         [1, 1]],

        [[5, 5],
         [6, 6],
         [4, 4]],

        [[8, 8],
         [9, 9],
         [7, 7]]])
```

Comment: This answer randomly shuffles the *same* way across all other axes.  It can be generalized to any axis via  `tensor.index_select(axis, torch.randperm(tensor.shape[axis]))`

Answer (score 1):

##### A two-part answer to shuffle along an axis.

- First, a direct solution giving different random permutation for each "row" of axis 1.
- Second, a generalized shuffle "row" function to shuffle any axis.

*Side note 1:*  Sorry my answer is several months late - I just had this question myself and I couldn't find an easy solution to the problem online, so here it is.

*Side note 2:* The nice answer from @GoodDeeds, as mentioned, gives the *same* random permutation across other axes.   This gives a *different* permutation across other axes.

##### First, an intuitive example for axis=1:

Input:

```
>>> a
tensor([[[1, 1],
         [2, 2],
         [3, 3]],

        [[4, 4],
         [5, 5],
         [6, 6]],

        [[7, 7],
         [8, 8],
         [9, 9]]])
```

Select random "rows" of axis 1.

```
>>> z = torch.rand(a.shape[:2]).argsort(1)  # define random "row" indices
>>> z = z.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, *(a.shape[2:]))  # reformat this for the gather operation.  Note that this works only for dim=1.
>>> output = a.gather(1, z)
```

Output:

```
>>> output
tensor([[[2, 2],
         [3, 3],
         [1, 1]],

        [[5, 5],
         [6, 6],
         [4, 4]],

        [[8, 8],
         [9, 9],
         [7, 7]]])
```

##### Second, a generalization to any axis:

It would be great if PyTorch had this function in its standard lib.  I'll raise an issue and link to this post.

```
def shufflerow(tensor, axis):
    row_perm = torch.rand(tensor.shape[:axis+1]).argsort(axis)  # get permutation indices
    for _ in range(tensor.ndim-axis-1): row_perm.unsqueeze_(-1)
    row_perm = row_perm.repeat(*[1 for _ in range(axis+1)], *(tensor.shape[axis+1:]))  # reformat this for the gather operation
    return tensor.gather(axis, row_perm)
```

Example:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> x
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

shuffle axis 0:

```
>>> shufflerow(x, 0)
tensor([[[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]],

        [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

shuffle axis 1

```
>>> shufflerow(x, 1)
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[16, 17, 18, 19],
         [12, 13, 14, 15],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

shuffle axis 2

```
>>> shufflerow(x, 2)
tensor([[[ 2,  0,  1,  3],
         [ 5,  6,  7,  4],
         [11, 10,  9,  8]],

        [[15, 14, 13, 12],
         [18, 17, 19, 16],
         [23, 20, 22, 21]]])
```

Comment: github issue:  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/71409